# Django filters ordering fix nulls position

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This class is needed to override standard PostgreSQL behavior and move NULL
values to the end of the list for DESC sorting and to the beginning of the list for ASC

api/filters.py

```
from django.db.models import F
from django_filters import OrderingFilter


class ImprovedOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    """
    This class is needed to override standard PostgreSQL behavior and move NULL
    values to the end of the list for DESC sorting and to the beginning of the list for ASC
    """

    def get_ordering_value(self, param):
        descending = param.startswith('-')
        param = param[1:] if descending else param
        field_name = self.param_map.get(param, param)
        ref = F(field_name)

        return ref.desc(nulls_last=True) if descending else ref.asc(nulls_first=True)
```

myapp/filters.py

```
class UserFilterSet(FilterSet):
    ordering = ImprovedOrderingFilter(
        fields=(
            ...
        )
    )
```

Comment: what is the problem here? are you facing any issues?

Comment: No problems, working code for other people